# How does R work with bigints?

Tags: r, bigint

I have an 18 digit int which R doesn't understand, it returns a different value from what I enter

```
options(digits = 22)
> as.numeric(123456789123456789)
[1] 123456789123456784
```

Also when using bit64 which has an integer64 class

```
> as.integer64(123456789123456789)
integer64
[1] 123456789123456784
```

Are there other packages that can interpret this number correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Use `as.integer64("123456789123456789")`. `123456789123456789` is a double (to avoid integer overflow) and thus subject to [floating point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059). `as.integer64(123456789123456789)` creates an integer64 from this double.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that is similar to the one suggested by @Roland; just using another library.

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz("123456789123456789")
#> x
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 123456789123456789
```

In this case, too, the number needs to be put in quotation marks to prevent floating-point rounding errors.